# Removing uninstallable Firefox extensions

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser-addons

How do I remove an extension from Firefox where the 'Uninstall' button is greyed out in the add-ons dialog?

I primarily want to remove the .Net framework assistant that recently appeared and AVG's safe search add on.

**UPDATE**

It seems Mozilla are remotely disabling the Microsoft plugins!

Answer (score 2):

If you run the AVG install again you can remove the safe search.  Most stuff can be found in your profiles folder if you want to remove it manually.  This lives under your user profile application data folder under mozilla firefox profiles. The actual path depends on your operating system.

Answer (score 2):

These are add-ons registered in the registry:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry

To remove you need to open Registry Editor, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions` and remove the respective extensions.

Comment: dangerous, but can be done...only for experienced SuperUsers! :)

Answer (score 2):

Full info [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions). What worked for me recently was to:

Delete (or rename) the following three files from the profile folder (the files will be regenerated upon application restart):

```
* extensions.cache
* extensions.ini
* extensions.rdf
```

Answer (score 0):

For the .Net Framework Assistant addon, Microsoft has given instructions on [**this page**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963707) on their Knowledge Base.

For AVG Safe Search, the instructions are [**here**](http://www.technipages.com/firefox-3-cant-uninstall-avg-safe-search-extension-because-uninstall-is-grayed-out.html).