# Firefox: uninstalled extensions still here after restart

Tags: firefox, uninstall, firefox-extensions

Using FF5.0 on Win7-64bits

I recently uninstalled several Firefox extensions that I didn't use, but even after several restart, they still appear in the Add-ons manager. Each one is greyed out and minimized, and with the message "XXX has been removed - [Restart now] - [Undo]".

If I click "Undo", nothing happens.
If I click "Restart now", Firefox does restart, but those messages are still here.

So I guess the extensions have been removed, but some bug prevents FF from removing those messages.

I found this question that I though might help: [Removing uninstallable Firefox extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/29273/removing-uninstallable-firefox-extensions) (although it's a bit old).
As suggested I tried to remove the "extension.ini" when Firefox was closed (I did not found the other files) but that didn't change anything.

How can I remove those messages? (I'd like to avoid creating a new profile and reinstalling all my extensions/search engines and so on.)

(The extensions are: CSHelper, Drag & DropZones, Firepicker, Stylish-Custom, Test Pilot.)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the extensions registry key in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\extensions

Be sure to backup your registry before deleting anything.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a "Mozilla" key under HKLM\SOFTWARE... Only "MozillaPlugins", but it's almost empty. I also checked under HKCU and I found a Mozilla\Firefox entry, but here again, almost empty... ? (It only has a "Crash Reporter" entry.)